# How to export only selected rows from datagridview into excel?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

How can I export selected rows from the dgv into excel? Below is my code for importing the excel and finding the value.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {               
            //this.textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;


            //string PathConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + textBox1.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes:\";";
            String PathConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + openFileDialog1.FileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=Yes:\";";                        
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(PathConn);
            OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [sheet1$]", conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            myDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        }
    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        try
        {          
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString().ToUpperInvariant().Contains(textBox1.Text.ToUpperInvariant()))
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Selected = true;                        
                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your problem only getting selected rows, or you have problem exporting to excel?

Comment: the above code works fine for selecting rows, but i need the code for exporting into excel(only selected).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you know how to export a DataTable to excel(you can use existing libraries like Aspose Cells or using Interop), so I just write the code for creating that DataTable:

```
private DataTable CreateDataTableFromSelectedRows()
{
    var dtToExport = new DataTable();
    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
    {
        var dr = row.DataBoundItem as DataRow;
        dtToExport.ImportRow(dr);
    }
    return dtToExport;
}
```

If you use [Aspose cells](http://www.aspose.com/.net/excel-component.aspx) it would simply become:

```
private void btnExportSelectedRows(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string filePath = "C:\\test.xlsx";
        Aspose.Cells.Workbook wb = new Aspose.Cells.Workbook();
        wb.FileFormat = Aspose.Cells.FileFormatType.Xlsx;

        Worksheet sheet = wb.Worksheets[0];

        DataTable dt = CreateDataTableFromSelectedRows();
        sheet.Cells.ImportDataTable(dt, true, "A1");
        wb.Save(filePath);
}
```

But by using the export code you provide it all become:
(I removed existing comments on the code for brevity)

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app  = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook =  app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;                   
    app.Visible = true;
    worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
    worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
    worksheet.Name = "Exported from gridview";
    for(int i=1;i<dataGridView1.Columns.Count+1;i++)
    {
         worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i-1].HeaderText;
    }

    // It's the part which we are interested in
    // we just need to change dataGridView1.Rows to dataGridView1.SelectedRows
    for (int i=0; i < dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count ; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<dataGridView1.Columns.Count;j++)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
        }
    }

    workbook.SaveAs("c:\\output.xls",Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive , Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

  app.Quit();
}
```

I guess it would do the trick.

Comment: can you also plz provide code for exporting dgv to excel including your above code. Sorry, I'm new to this field.

Comment: I've code for exporting the dgv into excel, but it will not export the selected rows. If you want that I'll provide you. thank u.

Comment: I think it saves us time, so please provide that code.

Comment: I just added the code, can you plz check it.

Comment: let me know if you can see the above code.

Comment: Sorry but I can't see it.

Comment: I can't add code in comment box, plz tell me where to add that code so that you can see.

Comment: I think it's better to append it to your own question.

Comment: Ok I get your edit, now I'll change that and add it to my answer.

Comment: I added code into answer part. can you see?

Comment: any update on that Vahid plz?

Comment: I need you help again.

Comment: the code which you have given for me to export selected record from dgv into excel have some errors.

Comment: upto searching the record from the dgv is okay, but when I'm exporting the particular record(single) is not coming, one blank excel with headers coming.

Comment: I guess I found the problematic part, I edited the post to solve the problem, let me know if it didn't.

Comment: sorry for the delay, let me check.

Comment: working now thankyou again, and can you help me to show the searched record at top(i mean searched records have to be at top). The below code is working for showing at top but only single record, I mean if dgv has more than one record with same value it is not showing two records at top. dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;

Answer (score 0):

See below code for exporting into Excel:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // creating Excel Application
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();


        // creating new WorkBook within Excel application
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook =  app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);


        // creating new Excelsheet in workbook
         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;                   

       // see the excel sheet behind the program
        app.Visible = true;

       // get the reference of first sheet. By default its name is Sheet1.
       // store its reference to worksheet
        worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
        worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;

        // changing the name of active sheet
        worksheet.Name = "Exported from gridview";


        // storing header part in Excel
        for(int i=1;i<dataGridView1.Columns.Count+1;i++)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i-1].HeaderText;
        }


        // storing Each row and column value to Excel sheet
        for (int i=0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1 ; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<dataGridView1.Columns.Count;j++)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
            }
        }


        // save the application
        workbook.SaveAs("c:\\output.xls",Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive , Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        // Exit from the application
        app.Quit();
    }
```