# Use latest IE on the webbrowser control and not the Emulation process? C# Code

Tags: c#

I've developed a simple desktop application to share with some colleagues. However once i added the webbrowser control, it seems to not run properly as it needs the latest IE to open pages such as Google Maps.
Is there c# code i can use to automatically have the web browser control use the latest browser/IE?

[How to export only selected rows from datagridview into excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496686/how-to-export-only-selected-rows-from-datagridview-into-excel)

this ANSWER DID NOT WORK.

Comment: None of the answers there helped me. The code did not work on the application and it certainly did not make the webbrowser control display google maps.

Comment: MohD's answer works for me. I made a new Windows Forms project, added a WebBrowser control, and then used this as Form1.cs: http://pastebin.com/DGuTQxXV Note that I changed IE 8 to IE 11.